# Sonar java analysis error Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.report.ActiveRulesPublisher

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am using SonarQube 5.6.5. My sonar java analysis failed with the below error message. couldnt find the resolution anywhere. kindly help.

**org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar**
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.report.ActiveRulesPublisher**
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:79)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.batch.rule.ActiveRules

```
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)
... 41 more
```

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException**
    at org.sonar.batch.rule.DefaultActiveRulesLoader.readPage(DefaultActiveRulesLoader.java:100)
    at org.sonar.batch.rule.DefaultActiveRulesLoader.load(DefaultActiveRulesLoader.java:60)
    at org.sonar.batch.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:102)
    at org.sonar.batch.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:63)
    at org.sonar.batch.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.provide(ActiveRulesProvider.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)
    ... 55 more

Comment: Post the specific error only don't copy paste. so please post your attempts so that we can help you!

Comment: Issue is resolved after deleting the data folder in sonarQube server. Thanks